# Gradual polygon reduction

Tags: mesh, retopology, remesh

Is there a way in Blender to automatically arrange a gradual mesh transition from highpoly to lowpoly?

For a clearer example, I want the front of the first rabbit and the back of the second from this image to exist in the same mesh, merging seamlessly into each other.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's an automatic way to gradually change the resolution but in *Sculpt* mode you can increase or decrease the resolution of the part you want by changing the *Detail Size* in the *Dyntopo* panel:

[image]

Then keep the *Draw* brush selected, lower its *Strength* down to 0 so that it won't affect the shape and sculpt where you want to change the resolution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Decimate modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) on the Collapse setting with a vertex group defining the area you want to simplify.

[image: Weights]

[image: Decimated]

This has the advantage of being nondestructive, so you can try out different settings.

Comment: Hello Colonel, yes but Decimate will act on the whole mesh, while he wants something gradual from front to back

Comment: @moonboots Edited.

Comment: yes, that's a nice solution